# How to fix "Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon" in flutter?

Tags: gradle, flutter, gradlew

I have set up my new PC and I'am already having some problems with Flutter. It used to run fine on my older PC.
I've installed Android Studio, Android SDK, Flutter, VS Code with Dart and Flutter plugins, and after that created new flutter project. After connecting my phone to PC and hitting F5 I'm getting this error:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "D:\FlutterProjects\quotes\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Command: D:\FlutterProjects\quotes\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
```

Flutter doctor looks fine.
Here are my gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

And gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

And the last thing, build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Can anyone help me with that problem?

Comment: Does it build if you disable the daemon - `org.gradle.daemon=false`?

Comment: Same thing happen with daemon disabled

Comment: Even if you run `D:\FlutterProjects\quotes\android\gradlew.bat app:properties` from the command line (i.e. not from AndroidStudio, without enabling the deamon)?

Comment: From what I can see it's still trying to start gradle daemon :/

Comment: I have tried running it with D:\FlutterProjects\quotes\android\gradlew.bat app:properties --no-daemon and now I'm getting this error: Project 'app' not found in root project 'quotes'.

Comment: Have you tried creating another project in the same way? How exactly did you create the project?

Answer (score 0):

run

```
flutter clean
```

it will clean your current build folder and cache, then when you run your Flutter App, a new Build folder will be created.

in most cases it fix it.